# Alamofire - Bulk API Call produces nil on second try iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, alamofire

I have a function called `GetCart()`

`GetCart()` function is:

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, producturl, encoding: .JSON).validate() .responseJSON(completionHandler: {response in
 switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            print("Validation Successful")
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }

})
```

This GetCart() function is passed in a loop like so through a button action method:

```
@IBAction func calltwice(sender: UIButton) {

    for all in 1...5{

        GetCart("24485814")
    }

}
```

On the first try this results in:

```
Validation Successful
Validation Successful
Validation Successful
Validation Successful
Validation Successful
```

Second click results in:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6006 "JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length.}
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6006 "JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length.}
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6006 "JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length.}
Validation Successful
Validation Successful
```

Regardless of how many times it goes through the loop ( 5 or 50) on the second click, only 2 always just goes through. Would aynone know as to why this is happening?

Comment: Have you find any solution for it?

Comment: @DharmbirSingh not sure - I thought it was just my server